# Влияет ли размер оперативной памяти на скорость загрузки файлов через интернет?

Tags: память, загрузка, скорость

Предположим у Ивана Ивановича десктопный компьютер, на котором он открывает только одно приложение одновременно. Когда Иван Иванович уходит на работу он ставит компьютер на закачку торрентов.

У Ивана Ивановича было 4 гб оперативной памяти. C 1 января, дед мороз подарил Ивану Ивановичу +4 гб(+100%) оперативной памяти. Все остальные параметры компьютера остались неизменными.

**Вопрос:** увеличится ли скорость скачивания торрентов у Ивана Ивановича, если он в это время никакие другие программы не открывает? Если да, то насколько увеличится?

*Примечание:*  скорость интернета у Иван Ивановича варьируется от 10 до 100 мбит в секунду от внешних, независимых от Иван Ивановича факторов.

Comment: Вряд-ли скорость скачивания увеличится. Лимитирует здесь скорость сети и скорость записи на диск, а не размер ОЗУ. Если ОЗУ стало больше, то теоретически программа закачки может увеличить размер буфера для данных в ОЗУ. Ну и что с того? Все равно потом из буфера надо сливать данные на диск, значит лимитирует диск и скорость сети, а вовсе не размер ОЗУ. А вот если увеличить скорость сети, и поставить SSD диск, то скорость скачивания торрентов может и увеличиться. Но тоже при условии, что у источника широкий канал. Если на том конце стоит диалап-модем, то увы.

Comment: А с другой стороны, если он качает 100 торрентов одновременно, ну или не знаю сколько и забивает под буфер торрент-клиента всё ОЗУ, то добавление памяти может и помочь. Но всё-равно это какой-то сферический вопрос в вакууме.

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну сколько там тот буфер? Имеет смысл делать буфер кратный кластеру файловой системы. Для NTFS это 64 кБ. Если 100 закачек по 64 кБ, то это 6 мегабайт, что гораздо меньше, чем 4 гига ОЗУ. Даже если сделать буфера по одному мегабайту, то 100 закачек это 100 мегабайт, что тоже гораздо меньше, чем 4 гига ОЗУ.

Comment: Кстати, пришла свежая мысль. Нужно запустить Ваш любимый торрент-клиент на 10-20-30 закачек и поглядеть в мониторе ОС, сколько ОЗУ будет использоваться этим клиентом. Если гораздо меньше, чем 4 гига, то добавление лишнего ОЗУ ничего не даст. А если сравнимо, то может быть добавление лишнего ОЗУ и поможет.